# Signing to modify PDAs -- how does the runtime know who is authorized and how to change it?

Tags: solana, anchor-solana

I have an instruction in Anchor code that creates a PDA like this:

```rust
#[account]
#[derive(Default)]
pub struct Device {
    pub ipv4: [u8; 4],
    pub hostname: String,
    bump: u8,
    status: DeviceStatus,
    authority: Pubkey,
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
#[instruction(local_key: Pubkey)]
pub struct RegisterDevice<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(init,
        space = 128,
        seeds = [local_key.as_ref()],
        bump,
        payer = authority,
    )]
    pub device: Box<Account<'info, Device>>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

I want to allow a *different* key (whose pubkey is known at the time of creation, and does not have access to the priv key of the original `authority`) to *update* the created `Device` PDA, and my first stab at this looks like below:

```rust
#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct UpdateDevice<'info> {
    #[account(mut)]
    pub authority: Signer<'info>,

    #[account(mut,
        has_one = authority,
        seeds = [authority.key().as_ref()],
        bump,
    )]
    pub device: Box<Account<'info, Device>>,

    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}
```

However, Anchor/the Solana runtime complains about a signing error, which means this approach is wrong. Since it's not a token account, the `Device` doesn't have an owner, yet the system seems to track that the original `authority` is the one who can sign for modifications -- if I've signed the transaction with the original provided key, the runtime doesn't seem to mind.

How can I implement what I'm looking to do?

Answer (score 0):

OK! Seems I've figured out the issue. h/t to Paulx for help.

As I thought, there is nothing special in the Solana runtime that tracks who is the "authority" on an account by default (Token Program accounts have owners as a property in the account, but that's at the program level...)

Anyway, the issue here I ran into is that Anchor RPC defaults `.signers([])` to the `provider` key (local wallet) if they are not provided, i.e., that method is not called in the `rpc`. I wasn't passing signers, cause I was using that magic before and assumed it would still work with a non-default signers due to all the reflection.

So make sure you pass your signers correctly kids!